# Angular ui grid: Add value of selected cell to model

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I currently have a grid that I created with Angular [ui-grid](http://ui-grid.info/) that allows the user to select a number of rows.  The first column of each row has an id number, and I would like to add the ids of the selected rows to an object in my model so that I can use those ids to query my database on the back end.

My problem is that I have not figured out how to access cell values, much less how to add the value of selected cells to my model.  So any help would be very much appreciated!

Here is the code for my grid that I use in my controller

```
        $scope.gridOptions = {
        enablePaginationControls: false,
        enableRowSelection: true,
        enableSelectAll: true,
        paginationPageSize: 25,
        enableHorizontalScrollbar: 0,
        enableVerticalScrollbar: 0,
        columnDefs: [
            {field: 'analysis_id',displayName: 'Analysis ID',width: '15%'}, 
            {field: 'study_id', displayName: 'Study ID',width: '15%'},
            {field: 'publisher', displayName: 'Publisher',cellFilter: 'titlecase',width: '20%'},
            {field: 'parent_company', displayName: 'Parent Company', cellFilter: 'titlecase',width: '30%'}
        ]};

    $scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function(gridApi) {
        $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$scope.gridApi.cellNav.on.navigate($scope,function(newRowCol, oldRowCol) {               
    console.log($scope.gridApi.grid.getCellValue(newRowCol.row,newRowCol.col));
});
```

Comment: I tried to add this, but it broke my controller with the following error  TypeError: Cannot read property 'cellNav' of undefined

Comment: @dsal1951, its to put inside onRegisterApi, after you assign $scope.gridApi

Answer (score 1):

Maybe **gridApi.selection.getSelectedRows();** is something you need.

*( ['ui.grid.selection'] dependence in app.module required)*

```
$scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function(gridApi){

    $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
    gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($scope,function(row){
        $scope.selectedObject = gridApi.selection.getSelectedRows();
        console.log ($scope.selectedObject);
    });
};
```